Are there different standards for the ordering of principal parts? If so, what are they called?
Are there different standards for the ordering of principal parts? If so, what are they called?
For instance, in my class we learn:

First principal part: The first person singular in the present active indicative
Second principal part: The present infinitive
Third principal part: The first person singular in the perfect active indicative
Fourth principal part: The perfect passive participle

Are there other standards? What are they called? Where/when did they originate?
Thank you so much.

Related question.
